# Adding double in groovy

Tags: groovy

I defined two doubles:

```
double abc1 = 0.0001;
double abc2 = 0.0001;
```

now if I print them:

```
println "Abc1 "+abc1;
println "Abc2 "+abc2;
```

it returns:

```
Abc1 1.0E-4

Abc2 1.0E-4
```

While if I add them:

```
println "Abc3 "+abc1+abc2;
```

It returns:

```
Abc3 1.0E-41.0E-4
```

rather than:

```
Abc3 2.0E-4
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: also writing "string" + var + "string" + var is an antipattern in groovy.  use "abc ${abc1+abc2}" or "abc ${abc1} ${abc2}" for less surprises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your method didn't work is that addition operations goes from left to right. You can instead do it like this:

```
println "answer "+(double)(abc1+abc2);
```

Answer (score 8):

This is because addition operator works from ***left to right*** and you start with string, hence the addition operator works as **concatenation** operator in your case.

---

This:

```
println "Abc3 "+abc1+abc2;
```

will be done step by step like this:

1. `println "Abc3 "+abc1+abc2;`
2. `println "Abc3 1.0E-4"+abc2;`
3. `println "Abc3 1.0E-41.0E-4";`

---

#### Solution

If you want to get the result you are expecting, do it like this:

```
println "Abc3 " + (abc1 + abc2);
```

Here you are *prioritizing* the **addition** before the **concatination**.